# Redirect output of program into a variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Can somebody help on this

I want to redirect the output from openssl to a variable in shell script. Like this

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey inp -in inenc -out [to some variable]
```

As of now I'm trying to achieve like this

```
var=$(openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey inp -in inenc -out >(xargs))
```

But instead of that I need some one liner code to do this without using xargs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because openssl emits to stdout by default, you can omit the whole `-out` part:

```
var=$(openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey inp -in inenc)
```

should work just fine.

Comment: lol, Thanks for that, I have forgotten that simple thing